# Matlab code is speeding up the playback of my video

Tags: matlab

```
% Download the videos
backgroundFish = VideoReader('swimmingWithFish.mp4');
backgroundFish.FrameRate = 24;
answer1 = read(backgroundFish);
[backgroundHeight, backgroundWidth, color, backgroundLength] = size(answer1);

% Set the length of the recorded video to the length of the background video
newVideoLength = backgroundLength;
% -----------------------------------------------


// some code

% Open a video file to save the green screen footage to
newVideo = VideoWriter('liveScreen.mp4','MPEG-4');
% the frame rate depends the length of the video and how fast
% it looks like. At 24 frames per second it equals the same length as
% original video but im sped up. As we lower it, the length of the
% video is increased
newVideo.FrameRate = 24;
open(newVideo);
// Sampling of code
writeVideo(newVideo,z);

% Show the rendered photo
image(z);


end
```

I have included code that was written to create a green screen. Everything is working fine except when I playback my new video it looks as though it is a fast forwarded version of the originals.

Comment: What software are you using to play back your video?

Comment: What does QuickTime itself report the frame rates (FPS) of the two movies as ("Show Movie Inspector" under the "Window" menu)?